# Exporting Multiple Components From An index.js File in react and its side effects

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, vite, tree-shaking

I wanna know if there is any side effects of exporting multiple components from an index.js file in an app created using vite/react(vite) or create-next-app(webpack) so that while importing, i can import multiple components in a single bracket like this

```
import { Button, CustomModal, Input } from '../ui';
```

so, i wanna know if i only import one component in a file. Does it import all of other components as well in the final build as they are all in a single object?, or if not, does it create an instance of them which consumes memory? or modern bundlers like vite or webpack can handle it on their own?

Right now i'm exporting components like this from components/ui/index.js:

```
import Button from './Button';
import BadgeRounded from './BadgeRounded';
import DropDown from './Dropdown';
import ToggleSwitch from './ToggleSwitch';
import Input from './Input';
import CustomTable from './CustomTable';
import RoundedInput from './RoundedInput';
import CustomModal from './Modal';
import GoBackWithText from './GoBackWithText';
import ActionButton from './ActionButton';
import CustomDatePicker from './DatePicker';
import CustomTimePicker from './TimePicker';
import RoundedCheckWithLabel from './RoundedCheckWithLabel';
import PicturesWall from './UploadPicturesWall';
import CheckWithLabel from './CheckWithLabel';
import TextArea from './TextArea';
import StarRating from './FiveStarRating';

export {
  StarRating,
  TextArea,
  CheckWithLabel,
  PicturesWall,
  RoundedCheckWithLabel,
  CustomTimePicker,
  CustomDatePicker,
  ActionButton,
  GoBackWithText,
  RoundedInput,
  CustomTable,
  Input,
  Button,
  BadgeRounded,
  DropDown,
  ToggleSwitch,
  CustomModal
};
```

I tried searching in vite's and webpack's documentation but i did not get the proper answer.

Comment: Nope it's correct , https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel

Comment: @Vikas i tested it using vite react, i created a new project and exported multiple images from a single file and then imported only one image in app.tsx, but when i created the build, it included all of the images, but i guess it does not matter in the end if you use all of the images, but im concerned about the memory usage each time i import a component or a image from index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `index.js` to be tree-shakable, for that you can use [agadoo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agadoo) to test it. Launch it on your `index.js`, by preferences after building it. If it is, nice ! Only the imported modules will be taken in the final bundle. If it's not, that mean all the modules in your `index.js` will be bundled in your code.

If it's not, you need to find the cause, it can be due to initialization in `const` or using external library outside their intended scope. Sadly `agadoo` doesn't tell you the exact cause.